# Make [collisions] a synonym of [collision]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

[collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collision) is the main tag, which, while rather vague IMO, at least has a wiki and about 1800 questions.

[collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collisions) is the possible duplicate, with no wiki and only 164 questions asked.

I have not conducted a thorough investigation into the quality of the questions under either tag but the couple I saw seemed to be better tagged [collision-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collision-detection).

I don't quite know how these things are supposed to be handled (and probably don't have the rep to do anything myself), so I thought I should bring this to people's attention on meta.

Comment: You've handled this appropriately. It should be brought to Meta, a consensus should be reached, and then a moderator will step in to merge the lesser tag into the greater tag, as well as create a synonym. That will elegantly handle the problem, with minimal or no disruptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I collided [collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collision) and [collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collisions) so hard they became one.

I left [collision-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collision-detection) alone. The [collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collision) wiki seems to be doing an OK job disambiguating for now. If I collided any more tags today I just might cause a singularity.